# Wait a moment befor showing an Intent

Tags: java, android

If you can help me I will be very grateful.
What I want to do is to lunch an intent in the background and show it after 5 seconds.

my code to show Intent is :

```
Intent intentt = new Intent(Palet_result.this, Rpalet_result.class);
startActivity(intentt);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use `Thread.sleep(5000);`

Comment: sorry but if i use Thread.sleep(5000); the intent will not be lunched firstly in background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a handler:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Palet_result.this, Rpalet_result.class);
              startActivity(intent);                                                

        }

   }, 5000);
```